# Using 'GROUP BY' while preferring rows associated in another table

Tags: mysql

I have a table `tbl_entries` with the following structure:

```
+----+------+------+------+
| id | col1 | col2 | col3 |
+----+------+------+------+
| 11 |    a |    b |    c |
| 12 |    d |    e |    a |
| 13 |    a |    b |    c |
| 14 |    X |    e |    2 |
| 15 |    a |    b |    c |
+----+------+------+------+
```

And another table `tbl_reviewlist` with the following structure:

```
+----+-------+------+------+------+
| id | entid | cola | colb | colc |
+----+-------+------+------+------+
|  1 |    12 |    N |    Y |    Y |
|  2 |    13 |    Y |    N |    Y |
|  3 |    14 |    Y |    N |    N |
+----+-------+------+------+------+
```

Basically, `tbl_reviewlist` contains reviews about the entries in `tbl_entries`. However, for some known reason, the entries in `tbl_entries` are duplicated. I am extracting the unique records by the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM `tbl_entries` GROUP BY `col1`, `col2`, `col3`;
```

However, any one of the duplicate rows from `tbl_entries` will be returned no matter they have been reviewed or not. I want the query to **prefer** those rows which have been reviewed. How can I do that?

EDIT: I want to prefer rows which have been reviewed but if there are rows which have not been reviewed yet it should return those as well.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking for here. What is the issue?

Comment: In the absence of any aggregating functions, the use of a GROUP BY clause is inappropriate. Perhaps you meant DISTINCT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a way with less repetition, but this should be a start:

```
select
  tbl_entries.ID,
  col1,
  col2,
  col3,
  cola, -- ... you get the idea ...
from (
select coalesce(min(entid), min(tbl_entries.ID)) as favID
from tbl_entries left join tbl_reviewlist on entid = tbl_entries.ID
group by col1, col2, col3
) as A join tbl_entries on tbl_entries.ID = favID
left join tbl_reviewlist on entid = tbl_entries.ID
```

Basically you distill the desired output to a list of core ID's and then re-map back to the data...

Comment: I just noticed that you had exactly the same as mine (plus the extra join) and posted before I did. I think you deserve the accept button.

Comment: @ypercube Hey, I guess great minds (and perhaps twisted ones) think alike.  Yours is definitely the shorter simpler query, hopefully the asker will accept the one most useful to them.  Either way, I hope we both at least get an up-vote :-)  Wow, we really both got `coalesce(min(), min())` separately.  Very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Have you actually tried anything?

A hint: The SQL standard requires that every column in the result set of a query with a `group by` clause must be either

- a grouping column
- an *aggregate function* — `sum()`, `count()`, etc.,
- a constant value/literal, or
- an expression derived solely from the above.

Some broken implementations (and I believe MySQL is one of them) allow other columns to be included and offer their own...creative...behavior. If you think about it, `group by` essentially says to do the following:

1. Order this table by the grouping expressions
2. Partition it into subsets based on the group by sequence
3. Collapse each such partition into a single row computing the aggregate expressions as you go.

Once you've done that, what does it mean to ask for something that isn't uniform across the collapsed group partition?

If you have a table `foo` containing columns A, B, C, D and E and say something like

```
select A,B,C,D,E from foo group by A,B,C
```

per the standard, you should get a compile error. Deviant implementations [usually] treat this sort of query as the [rough] equivalent of

```
select *
from foo t
join ( select A,B,C
       from foo
       group by A,B,C
     ) x on x.A = t.A
        and x.B = t.B
        and x.C = t.C
```

But I wouldn't necessarily count on that without review the documentation for the specific implementation that your are using.

If you want to find just reviewed entries, then something like this:

```
select *
from tbl_entries t
where exists ( select *
               from tbl_reviewlist x
               where x.entid = t.id
             )
```

will do you. If, however, you want to find reviewed entries that are duplicated on `col1`, `col2` and `col3` then something like this should do you:

```
select *
from tbl_entries t
join ( select col1,col2,col3
       from tbl_entries x
       group by col1,col2,col3
       having count(*) > 1
     ) d on d.col1 = t.col1
        and d.col2 = t.col2
        and d.col3 = t.col3
where exists ( select *
               from tbl_reviewlist x
               where x.entid = t.id
             )
```

Since your problem statement is rather unclear, another take might be something along these lines:

```
select t.col1            ,
       t.col2            ,
       t.col3            ,
       t.duplicate_count ,
       coalesce(x.review_count,0) as review_count
from      ( select col1 ,                       
                   col2 ,                       
                   col3 ,                       
                   count(*) as duplicate_count  
            from tbl_entries
            group by col1 ,
                     col2 ,
                     col3
          ) t
left join ( select cola, colb, colc , count(*) as review_count
            from tbl_reviewList
            group by cola, colb, colc
            having count(*) > 1
          ) x on x.cola = t.col1
             and x.colb = t.col2
             and x.colc = t.col3
order by sign(coalesce(x.review_count,0)) desc ,
         t.col1 ,
         t.col2 ,
         t.col3
```

This query

- summarizes the `entries` table, developing a count of how many time seach col1/2/3 combination exists.
- summarizes the review table, developing a count of reviews for each cola/b/c combination
- joins them together matching cols a:1, b:2 c:3
- orders them

  - preferring reviewed items to non-reviewed items by placing them first,
  - then by the col1/2/3 values.

Comment: It will return only those rows which have been reviewed. I don't want only those rows, I want to prefer rows which have been reviewed but if a combination of (col1, col2, col3) is not reviewed yet then any of the unique row can be returned.

Comment: Your problem statement is still unclear, but see my amended answer for another stab in the dark.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT e.col1, e.col2, e.col3, 
       COALESCE(MIN(r.entid), MIN(e.id)) AS id 
FROM tbl_entries AS e
  LEFT JOIN tbl_reviewlist AS r
    ON r.entid = e.id
GROUP BY e.col1, e.col2, e.col3 ;
```

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2c2e45/1)**

Comment: @ypercube heh you cheated!  If there were any other values besides those being grouped on, you'd need a sub-query or another set of joins back to get the interesting data...

Comment: @ebyrob Of course. If they need the other columns from table `tbl_reviewlist` for example, another join will be needed.

Comment: @ypercube Doh, I didn't expect anyone to flip the accept!  By "cheated" I was trying to pay you a compliment.  This query is only half as long as mine and I definitely wouldn't have thought of turning it inside out like that to trim the extra fat.  (PS - I realized my query also falls short if more than one review exists per entry...)

Comment: @ebyrob Thnx, I certainly was not offended by "cheated".